# SASS generates two separate rules for same class using extend and mixins

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

In this SCSS code, I'm using mixin `btn-structure` and extend `%red-color` to get all declarations under one class contrary to my expectation SCSS output two separate rules for the same class as shown in output below:

```
%red-color{
  color: red }

@mixin btn-structure 
  ($text-case: null, $text-shadow: null, $decoration: none ){

display: inline-block;

  text: {
          decoration: $decoration;
            transform: $text-case;
            shadow: $text-shadow }

}

.link-btn{
  @include btn-structure($text-case: 'uppercase', $decoration: underline);
  @extend %red-color
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.link-btn {
  color: red;
}

.link-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: "uppercase";
}
```

I don't want the SASS to output two separate rules belonging to same class how to get SASS to output one rule if that belongs to one class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual behaviour and a use-case of Sass `@extend`.

### Explanation

To make it clear, update your code as below

```
%red-color{
  color: red
}

@mixin btn-structure ($text-case: null, $text-shadow: null, $decoration: none ){
  display: inline-block;
  text: {
    decoration: $decoration;
    transform: $text-case;
    shadow: $text-shadow 
  }
}

.link-btn{
  @extend %red-color;
  @include btn-structure($text-case: 'uppercase', $decoration: underline);
}

.test-class{
  @extend %red-color;
  @include btn-structure($text-case: 'uppercase', $decoration: underline);
}
```

Which would **compile** as,

```
.link-btn, .test-class {
  color: red;
}

.link-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: "uppercase";
}

.test-class {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: "uppercase";
}
```

As you could see, `@extend` is used to "share a set of CSS properties from one selector to another", which can be clubbed together (`.link-btn, .test-class`). Whereas, `@include` is used to insert the styles where ever required, which is not clubbed.

### Solution

For your requirement, you can resort to `@include` and declare a mixin `@mixin red-color` as below,

```
%red-color{
  color: red
}

@mixin red-color{
  color: red
}

@mixin btn-structure ($text-case: null, $text-shadow: null, $decoration: none ){
  display: inline-block;
  text: {
    decoration: $decoration;
    transform: $text-case;
    shadow: $text-shadow 
  }
}

.link-btn{
  @include red-color;
  @include btn-structure($text-case: 'uppercase', $decoration: underline);
}
```

### Output

And the compiled css will be,

```
.link-btn {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: "uppercase";
}
```

Hope this helps.